# unzip file, which directory was created?

Tags: shell, zip

Objective:

After expanding archive `a.zip` by using command `unzip` on `Ubuntu 12.10`, assign the name of the folder `a.zip` expanded to to `bash` variable `v`.

`a.zip` is assumed and guaranteed to expand to a single folder, rather than multiple folders.

Example:

If `unzip a.zip` expands to folder `./foo/`, `echo $v` should return `foo`.

My environment:

```
GNU/Linux (kernel 3.5.0-25-generic)
Ubuntu 12.10    
bash v4.2.37(1)-release
UnZip 6.00 of 20 April 2009, by Debian. Original by Info-ZIP.
```

---

Current workaround I am *unhappy* with: expand via `unzip -d bar a.zip` then `v=$(ls -1 bar)` gives the right result, but messes up the filesystem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here you go:

```
v=$(unzip a.zip | grep -m1 'creating:' | cut -d' ' -f5-)
```

**Explanation**

- `$(...)` is a capture shell. It captures the output of the commands within it and substitutes them like a variable.
- The output of the `unzip` command is piped to `grep`, which is passed the argument `-m1` to make it return only the first result and the text `creating:`, which is part of the text `unzip` prints to stdout when it creates a directory. `grep` prints `creating: foo/` to stdout, which is piped `cut`.
- `cut` is used to print all columns (separated by spaces) after the second one. We specify from 5 until the end of the line though because the word `creating:` is prefixed with a few spaces. We want to use all of the columns until the end of the line in case the directory name has spaces in it. The final output is `foo/`.

Comment: Thanks! :) I like the `-m1` on `grep` and I did not know about `cut` printing to the end via `-fN-` (omitting last field number). You taught me something! For this -> upvote! Have you not used just one tool (e.g. `awk`) because 1. `grep` and `cut` are more widespread than `awk` and 2. you find what you wrote more "readable"? I'd like to hear your rationale, since one could concoct a one-liner, like so:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15776352/ PS: you don't need the quotes, no word-splitting in bash at variable assignment time. `v=$(echo a b)` is the same as `v="$(echo a b)"`

Comment: It is easier to select all of the fields until the end of the line with `cut` than with it is with `awk`. It's also a bit more readable in my opinion. That one-liner is interesting. I'll have to read more about `awk`.

Using quotation marks in variable assignments is a bad habit of mine that resulted from a text editor that colored the text inside of quotation marks nicely. Also, my default language is C.

Comment: This is a really good tip but it seems getting output folder this way breaks unzipping process somehow. Is there a way to get output dir without breaking unzipping process?

Answer (score 2):

- You can use `unzip -l` to list the archive's content and parse the output
- Or you can list the directory, extract the arcive that list the directory again and compare the two listings using `diff`

Comment: Evan's solution is more direct: extracts _and_ parses out the dir name.. (although your idea is good, and the basis for Evan's solution.. for this - I am upvoting with thanks..)

Answer (score 1):

The [AVFS](http://avf.sourceforge.net/) filesystem presents a view of the filesystem where every archive file `/path/to/foo.zip` is accessible as a directory `~/.avfs/path/to/foo.zip#`.

```
mountavfs
ls ~/.avfs$PWD/foo.zip\#
```

If that `ls` command shows a single directory, then unzipping the zip file will create that directory and create files underneath it. Do note that a zip file may or may not be organized this way.

Here's a snippet that checks your assumption, and sets `dir` to the directory name if applicable. Warning: if the zip file contains files whose name begins with a `.` (dot files), they are ignored.

```
zip_directory_name () {
  case $1 in
    /*) ;;
    *) set "$PWD/$1";;
  esac
  cd ~/.avfs${1}\# || exit 2
  set -- *
  if [ $# -eq 1 ] && [ -d "$1" ]; then
    printf %s "$1"
  else
    return 1 # more than one top-level file, or a single non-directory
  fi
}
dir=$(zip_directory_name foo.zip) || exit $?
```

Answer (score 1):

Be unhappy with your workaround if you like, but it's actually the correct solution.

```
d="`mktemp -d`"
unzip -d "$d" "$zipfile"
v="`basename "$d"/*`"
mv "$d"/"$v" "$v"
rmdir "$d"
echo "$v"
```

This is verbose, but - as long as there really is only one dir in the zipfile, which you should probably check first - it's reliable.

`ls` and `grep` is less reliable because it depends on how output looks like. In a different locale, there may not be any "creating:" string. In the next version of unzip, it could be changed for whatever reasons.